# Allow Mobile internet to ssh in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, ssh, ip

I've set up security group for more security to allow only known Ip address to access my EC2 instance. So for that, I have added know IP address in the inbound rule to allow ssh access. But it's not allowing ssh connection when trying to connect through mobile internet. because mobile internet IP address continuously changes. so how can I get the public IP address when connecting net through mobile?

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally your mobile gives you IP address dynamically and every time you will get a new IP. But all these IPs usually fall within a range. So you can ALLOW a CIDR which contains your IP in the inbound rule. For example your IP is A.B.C.D then you can give a CIDR A.B.C.D/24 which will match all IPs that start with A.B.C.(1-255). But if you really need to get a public IP you will need to talk to your Mobile company